# matlab gui handles for unknown matrix size

Tags: matlab, user-interface, for-loop, matrix, handle

I am writing a GUI now which contains a button that load a matrix:

```
function Load_Profile_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to Load_Profile (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

[FileName PathName] = uigetfile('*.mat','MATLAB Files');
handles.matrix=importdata([PathName FileName]);
```

next, i want to define each column of this matrix to be different channel for example:

```
handles.Ch01Gr01=handles.matrix.Data(:,2);
handles.Ch01Gr02=handles.matrix.Data(:,3);
handles.Ch01Gr03=handles.matrix.Data(:,4);
handles.Ch01Gr04=handles.matrix.Data(:,5);
handles.Ch01Gr05=handles.matrix.Data(:,6);
handles.Ch01Gr06=handles.matrix.Data(:,7);
handles.Ch01Gr07=handles.matrix.Data(:,8);
```

In case i dont know how many columns there are in this matrix,
is there any option to solve this in `for loop` (or anyother idea will be good aswell )to run on this matrix dimension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a cell array for `channel`:

```
numch = size(handles.matrix, 2);
for i = 1:numch
    handles.Ch01Gr{i} = handles.matrix.Data(:, i);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the number of column before entering the loop and then create dynamic fields to name them according to the loop index (Check [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html)).

Here is a sample GUI in which pressing the button results in loading matrix `A` (a magic 4x4 matrix...`A = magic(4)`), which I stored in file 'A.mat'.

```
function LoadDataGUI
clc
clear
hfigure = figure('Position',[200 200 100 100]);

handles.LoadButton = uicontrol('Style','push','Position',[50 50 50 20],'String','Load','Callback',@(s,e) LoadDataCllbck);

guidata(hfigure,handles);

    function LoadDataCllbck

        handles = guidata(hfigure);

        %// Load matrix. A is actually a magic(4) matrix.
        handles.Data = load('A.mat');

        %// Check # of columns
        NumCol = size(handles.Data.A,2);

        for k = 2:NumCol

            %// Create dynamic field name
            CurrField = sprintf('Ch01Gr%i',k-1);

            %// Assign it to the handles structure.
            handles.(CurrField) = handles.Data.A(:,k);

        end

        guidata(hfigure,handles);
    end

end
```

Here, `CurrField` look like this at every iteration:

```
CurrField =

Ch01Gr1


CurrField =

Ch01Gr2


CurrField =

Ch01Gr3
```

You can customize the format as you want with `sprintf` of course.

After pressing the button, here is the content of the `handles` structure:

```
       LoadButton: 329.0085
          Data: [1x1 struct]
       Ch01Gr1: [4x1 double]
       Ch01Gr2: [4x1 double]
       Ch01Gr3: [4x1 double]
```

Don't forget the good practice of pre-allocating memory, especially if your data is large.

Hope that helped!